# How to use activation function on part neurons from one layer in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

For example, there is a tensor

```
a=[[1,2,3,4,5],
  [2,3,4,5,6]]

indices =[[1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I would only like to use activation on the elements (from a) whose index are with value 1 (from b). For example, I only want to use activation function on the elements from a with the indices [0,0], [0,2], [1,1] .

Thanks!

Comment: Is there typo in `indices [0,0], [0,1], [1,1] `? I think you want `indices [0,0], [0,2], [1,1] `, right?

Comment: You are correct, I have revised this typo. Thanks you. Do you have answer to my question? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks you very much, I have tried these functions, they actually work. But is very hard to use. I think the answers below would be more efficient. Thank you again.

Comment: yes!!! I didn't try this, but I feel if you will code 
`indices_true = tf.where(a, indices)`
`val = tf.gather_nd(a, indices_true)`, then `val` will become the tensor that you can use in activation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where):

`tf.where(tf.cast(indices, dtype=tf.bool), tf.nn.sigmoid(a), a)`

For your example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6]], dtype=tf.float32)
indices = tf.constant([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], 
dtype = tf.int32)
result = tf.where(tf.cast(indices, dtype=tf.bool), tf.nn.sigmoid(a), a)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(result))
```

This prints:

```py
[[ 0.7310586   2.          0.95257413  4.  5. ]
 [ 2.          0.95257413  4.          5.  6 ]]
```

Comment: Good way to perfectly solve my question, thank you very much.